# *.properties files cannot be found when running apps from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sapui5

I encountered a problem with internationalization when developing an OpenUI5 project in VS2013. The `i18n.properties` cannot be found:

> "GET http://localhost:28091/i18n/i18n.properties 404 (Not Found) sap-ui-core.js:126 "

Here is my project setting:

### `./i18n/i18n.properties`

```
showHello=Hello
```

### `./internationization/Main.controller.js`

```js
onInit: function() {
  var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleName : "i18n.i18n"
  });
  // ...
},
```

### `./internationization/Main.view.xml`

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="internationization.Main" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
  <Page title="Title">
    <Button text="{i18n>showHello}"/>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem using Visual Studios development webserver.

You have to configure it to deploy .properties files by providing a mime map in the web.config in the root of your project:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".properties" mimeType="application/text"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Just add the `<mimeMap/>` element and its parents if missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify absolute path while instantiating `ResorceModel`.

That is path will start from project name, so if *myProject* is name of your project then code will be:

```
var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleName : "myProject.i18n.i18n"
});
```

Comment: @Dopwdev   Thank you for your reply. but it seems that it is not working as expected.